# how to show path to file in the Emacs mode-line?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In the mode-line appears the name of the buffer I am working with (argf.rb):

[image]

For a buffer visiting a file, is it possible to display the absolute file name (i.e., include the path)?

Comment: Here's the actual answer to the question asked: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/63584/36074

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**First**, what you see is *buffer* name, not *file* name. Try to open two files with the same names (in different directories) and see what I mean.

**Second**, yes, I am sure it is possible - just customize [`mode-line-format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html).

**Third**, it might not be such a great idea - the mode line is already quite crowded and the long path will just not fit. I know it sounds great now, but you will hate it the next day.

Instead, put the path into the **title bar**:

```
(setq frame-title-format
      '(buffer-file-name "%b - %f" ; File buffer
        (dired-directory dired-directory ; Dired buffer
         (revert-buffer-function "%b" ; Buffer Menu
          ("%b - Dir: " default-directory))))) ; Plain buffer
```

Comment: I would also recommend enabling [`uniquify`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html), which updates the buffer name in sane ways when you're visiting multiple files with the same name.

Comment: Is there a function I can use to show it in the mini buffer?

Comment: @PeterPrevos: `M-: buffer-file-name RET`

Answer (score 1):

What I do is to create a bind to show the file name in the minibuffer

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-f C-n") (lambda () (interactive) (message (buffer-file-name))))`

Maybe there is already a feature for that that I don't know